# Flyback diodes for motors wired in parallel

Tags: motor, diodes, parallel, flyback, dual

When driving two DC motors wired in parallel, do they each require their own flyback diode or can they share a single diode?

Comment: One is ok. Since they are parallel, the the diode will catch any spike thru it.

Comment: Depends on the distance. If motor A is close to your driver but motor B is far away and only B has a diode, you can still fry your driver.

Comment: Motor A & Motor B would be not more than 3cm (~1 inch) from each other and sharing the same conductor to the driver. Main reason I ask is virtually every circuit or diagram I can find has a flyback per motor (though admittedly not usually wired in parallel)